# Dual of linear program with several quadratic constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, duality-theorems, quadratic-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

Let $ \mathcal{P}$ be a convex problem with linear objective and quadratic constraints, 
$$ \eqalign{
\mathcal{P}: & \min_{x,t} -t \\
   & \text{s.t.} \\
{\color{blue}{\mu_k}}:  & a^H_k x + a^T_k x^{*} - x^H D_k x + t p_k + r_k \leq 0, k = 1, \dots, K, \\
{\color{blue}{\lambda}}:  & x^H C x - P \leq 0, \\
{\color{blue}{\nu}}:  & diag(x) x^{*} - d 1 \preccurlyeq 0, \\
{\color{blue}{\beta}}:  & -t \leq 0.
}
$$
$ p_k, r_k \geq 0 $,
$ x \in \mathbb{C}^N $,
$ C $ is a diagonal matrix with real non-negative elements,
$ D_k \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N} $ is a symmetric positive semidefinite (rank-one)
$\mu_k, \lambda, \nu, \beta $ are the KKT multipliers

$ (\cdot)^H $ denotes Hermitian transpose
$ (\cdot)^{*} $ denotes the complex conjugate
$(\cdot)^T $ denotes the transpose.

Lagrangian:
$$
\eqalign
{
L(x,t,\mu_k,\lambda,\nu,\beta) = -t + \sum_k \mu_k (a^H_k x + a^T_k x^{*} - x^H D_k x + t p_k + r_k) + \lambda (x^H C x - P) + \nu^T (diag(x) x^{*} - d1) - t \beta
}
$$
**Objective:**
Find the dual of $ \mathcal{P} $ analytically.

**My attempt:**
I am stuck at this point by the following reasons. From the stationarity conditions, I would normally try to find $ x $ (and $ t $) and then replace them in the Lagrangian $ L(x,t,\mu_k,\lambda,\nu,\beta) $such that it only depends on the KKT multipliers $ \mu_k,\lambda,\nu,\beta $. However, from the stationarity conditions, I cannot find a way to get rid of $ x $ (as you can see). Also, the complementary slackness conditions do not seem to help at this point.

From stationarity conditions:
$$
\eqalign
{
(\sum_k \mu_k D_k - \lambda C - diag(\nu))x = \sum_k \mu_k a_k \\
\sum_k \mu_k p_k = (1 + \beta) 
}
$$

Comment: What techniques can be used when $x$ cannot be obtained from the stationarity conditions?

Comment: You mean to find the solution analytically? In practice you just use something like projected gradient descent.

Comment: Yes, I would like to find an analitical solution. Any source that has treated problems like this is also welcomed.

Comment: What is the question? Are you just looking to formulate a dual? The standard technique is to reformulate the primal by using a different x for each nonlinear constraint, and adding extra constraints that all the x have to be equal. That typically turns deriving the dual into a trivial task.

Comment: @LinAlg, I am looking to find the dual analytically. Can you provide more details about your approach to find the dual of the problem? As I have mentioned, I reached a point where I cannot continue manipulating the expressions.

Comment: @Dunkel I was writing the answer, but the Lagrangian is quadratic in $x$ and $t$, so finding the analytic minimum is trivial (there is no need to introduce a new $x$ for each constraint). My first suggestion is to write everything with real variables, so replace $x$ with $y + z i$.

Comment: On the stationarity conditions that you post: the first one is easily solvable for $x$ (just invert the matrix on the left hand side); if the second condition is satisfied then $t$ can be any real number as it does not affect the value of the Lagrangian (look at how the dual of a linear optimization problem is derived).

Comment: @LinAlg, thank you for your suggestions. Regarding your second comment, the matrix $(- \sum_k \mu_k D_k + \lambda C + diag(\nu)) $ seems to be positive semidefinite. Thus, it may not be invertible (right?). At best, it could be positive definite. Should I enforce positive definiteness on this matrix?

Comment: Good point. This is treated on page 651 of Convex Optimization by Boyd&Vandenberghe.

Comment: @LinAlg, thank you. I will give it a try considering your advices.

Comment: There is a new Operations Research community in Stackexchange that has started its beta phase recently.